# Node JS application get stuck at resolve()

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-cognito

I am facing an issue in my node js application while listing the aws cognito users.

This issue is coming only while i have more than 60 cognito users.

[Reference of API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUsers-property)

Below is my code snippet.

```
function isAllowedToDeleteOrRevokeUsers(cognitoidentityserviceprovider, params, listUsers, adminUserList) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           logger.log("ERROR", "Error while calling listUsers API : " + err);
           reject({ code: 404, msg : err.message});
       } else {
           data.Users.forEach(function(user) {
               if (isUserASystemAdmin(user)) {
                   adminUserList.users.push(user);
               }
           });
           if (data.PaginationToken != undefined) {
                params.PaginationToken = data.PaginationToken;
                isAllowedToDeleteOrRevokeUsers(cognitoidentityserviceprovider, params, listUsers, adminUserList);
           } else {
                // We've reached the end
                let totalCognitoAdminUsers = 0;
                let totalCognitoAdminUsersToDelete = 0;  

                adminUserList.users.forEach(function(adminUser) {
                    if (isCognitoUser(adminUser)) {
                        totalCognitoAdminUsers++;
                        if (listUsers.indexOf(adminUser.Username) > -1) {
                           totalCognitoAdminUsersToDelete++;
                        }
                    }
                });

               if(totalCognitoAdminUsers != 0 && (totalCognitoAdminUsers == totalCognitoAdminUsersToDelete)) {
                   reject({ code: 404, msg : "Cannot alter last Admin User controlled by standard authentication"});
               } else {
                   console.log("Return Success");
                   resolve();
               }
           }
       }
    });
  });
};
```

This function is working fine when i am less than 60 users, But as per [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html#API_ListUsers_RequestSyntax) we can only read 60 users at a time, In that case i am sending **paginationtoken** in the params.

My code is getting stucked while `resolve()` line.

If i remove below piece of code, than it will work.

```
 if (data.PaginationToken != undefined) {
    params.PaginationToken = data.PaginationToken;                    
    isAllowedToDeleteOrRevokeUsers(cognitoidentityserviceprovider, params, listUsers, adminUserList);
 }
```

Any help?

Please let me know if any further things are needed.

Comment: If I read your braces corretly, you're not resolving or rejecting in the if-statement you want to set the PaginationTokens. You should do that to complete a promise

Comment: Can you please explain to me how? Or please post the updated code in the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Is any error thrown in the terminal? Like `Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded` or something? That recursive call to `isAllowedToDeleteOrRevokeUsers` seems very dangerous to me.

Comment: @BennettHardwick not any error, My code is getting stucked at `resolve()`
And at UI side, I am getting error `Network error`

Comment: @JayeshDhandha I guess you know how Promises are working since you're using them. A promise is like a placeholder which will result in a specific value, whenever you call `resolve(value)` or you can terminate a promise whenever an error occurred by calling `reject(value/error/whateverMessage)`. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: cognitoidentityserviceprovider supports promise by default: `cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params).promise();` You don't need to create your own promise; This will simplify the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the mentioned `if` statement being true, you are going down a recursion of your function: `isAllowedToDeleteOrRevokeUsers(…)`.

You should not make recursive calls inside the promise, but resolve the promise for each page and re-execute it for each new page of the pagination.

In other words: make sure that each path in the logic inside the promise leads to a `resolve()` or `reject()` call. If your app logic requires recursion, re-structure that function, that on each recursion a new promise is created and resolved.

Comment: Thank you!
feela :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following code:

```
function isAllowedToDeleteOrRevokeUsers(cognitoidentityserviceprovider, params, listUsers, adminUserList) {
    return cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params).promise().then((data) => {
        data.Users.forEach(function(user) {
            if (isUserASystemAdmin(user)) {
                adminUserList.users.push(user);
            }
        });
        if (data.PaginationToken != undefined) {
            params.PaginationToken = data.PaginationToken;
            return isAllowedToDeleteOrRevokeUsers(cognitoidentityserviceprovider, params, listUsers, adminUserList);
       } else {
            // We've reached the end
            let totalCognitoAdminUsers = 0;
            let totalCognitoAdminUsersToDelete = 0;  

            adminUserList.users.forEach(function(adminUser) {
                if (isCognitoUser(adminUser)) {
                    totalCognitoAdminUsers++;
                    if (listUsers.indexOf(adminUser.Username) > -1) {
                       totalCognitoAdminUsersToDelete++;
                    }
                }
            });
            if(totalCognitoAdminUsers != 0 && (totalCognitoAdminUsers == totalCognitoAdminUsersToDelete)) {
                throw new Error({ code: 404, msg : "Cannot alter last Admin User controlled by standard authentication"});
            }
            console.log("Return success");
            return;
       }
    }).catch((err) => {
        logger.log("ERROR", "Error while calling listUsers API : " + err);
        throw new Error({ code: 404, msg : err.message});
    })
}
```

I have done slight improvements to original code, the original code makes lot of promises which will be stuck in pending state as expect at final recurssion end condition promise is never resolved. I am using implicit promise chaining by returning promise in then block of promise, this makes all promises to chain together. Once code reached to end of recurssion then every promise in the chain will be resolved. This implementation is using pure promises so it is easy to understand.

Comment: You should explain your code to help others understand what you've changed.

As far as I can see you only added a return statement which won't have any effect, since it is inside a lambda function `then((data) => { ...`

Comment: Sorry, I have added explanation now, is it fine or I need to explain further.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your changes. I am not sure that this is working though, but I am no expert with Promises. Don't you have to add another .then() to handle the Promise at the highest level of `return isAllowedToDeleteOrRevokeUsers`?

Comment: @EatYaFood then is not required, when we return promise within a then block then it gets chained into the same promise. Please see [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises#queuing_asynchronous_actions)